# Why am I not able use round in an extension?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I'm trying to make this `customRound` func, but Xcode complaining that ***can not convert value of type () to Double***
How could I possibly solve this problem?

```
extension Double {

    func customRound(zeros: Int) -> Double {
      return round(Double(zeros)*self) / Double(zeros)
    }
    
}
```

update:

```
extension Double {

    func customRound(digits: Int) -> Double {
        return Darwin.round(pow(10.0, Double(digits))*self) / pow(10.0, Double(digits))
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Your update works fine.  You could assign `pow(10.0, Double(digits))` to a `let` to avoid computing it twice, but the compiler probably optimizes that out anyway.

Comment: @vacawama: I wanted to do that one as you said, but I told myself why I should create an internal constant, but I am agree with you. so you think it is better use a constant instead of computing it twice? right?

Comment: It's probably just personal preference.  I'd use the `let`, others may not.  The internal constant will be optimized away and is closer to what you'd want the compiler to do.  I suspect though that both will result in the same code being generated.

Comment: I am most agree with your preference, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift thinks you are trying to call the mutating `round()` function of `Double` instead of the built-in `round()` which is part of the Darwin module.  You can fix this by explicitly specifying `Darwin.round()`:

```
extension Double {

    func customRound(zeros: Int) -> Double {
        return Darwin.round(Double(zeros) * self) / Double(zeros)
    }

}
```

Swift prefers the one defined on Double because it is trying to be helpful. Since you don't have to specify `self.` when calling a method in an extension, it thinks you meant `self.round(...)` thus trying to apply the mutating `round` on `self` when you wanted the Darwin version.

In addition to using `Darwin.` to select the desired `round` function, you can specify any framework that includes `Darwin` such as `UIKit` or `Foundation`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226221/discussion-on-answer-by-vacawama-why-am-i-not-able-use-round-in-an-extension).

Answer (score 2):

Double have both `.round()`and `.rounded()` with the former being mutating. If you want to return the value, you need to use the latter.

Here's how you can use the non-mutating function [Double.rounded()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2886778-rounded)

```
extension Double {
    func customRound(zeros: Int) -> Double {
        return (Double(zeros) * self).rounded() / Double(zeros)
    }
}

extension Double {
    func customRound(digits: Int) -> Double {
        return (pow(10.0, Double(digits)) * self).rounded() / pow(10.0, Double(digits))
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct reply but could be more efficient in not having to call POW twice. May not be guaranteed to optimise out.

Answer (score 0):

An extension of a previous reply with a safer optimisation logic.

```
extension Double {
    func rounded(toDecimal decimal: Int) -> Double {
        let multiplier = pow(10.0, Double(decimal))
        let value = Double(self * multiplier).rounded()
        return value / multiplier
    }
}
```